# Google Scripts Simple Search

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to search a sheet for a value in a sheet, and then return the row and the column where the value was found.

I am well-versed in VBA and have used the `.Find` function to accomplish this very easily. However, after searching for the last 30 minutes online, I have been stunned to discover that is is so hard to find the code for this extremely simple function. I feel like I am in the twilight zone. Does Javascript really not have anything analogous to `.Find`? If so, why is this language used so much when VBA appears to be able to accomplish the same tasks in a much more simple manner? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are calling something like `mysheet.getDataRange().getValues()`, which returns the contents of a google sheet as an array of arrays, eg, `[[row1A, row1B], [row2A, row2B]]`.

With JS, you can get the index of a value in an array using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which returns the index of the found item or `-1` if the item is not in the array. I don't think you can directly search across the two nested arrays. Instead, you could try iterating over the outer array and searching the inner array. Something like this:

```
// get data from google sheet, doing something like this
var data = mysheet.getDataRange().getValues()

// define our own function
function findItem(data) {
  // loop over outer array
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];                   // get the inner array
    var idx = row.indexOf(searchValue);  // search for value
    // if the value is found, return [row, column] 
    if (idx > -1) {
      return [i, idx];
    }
  }

// call the function
var res = findItem(data);
var row = res[0];
var col = res[1];
```

Comment: You make an interesting point.  I hung my answer on the last two sentences of the question.  And this will only work for certain specific types of data sources...

Comment: Thanks Dustin, I was able to use this to get get what I need. Much appreciated!

Comment: `0` is a valid index. `idx>0` will exclude Col1

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples and oranges. JavaScript and VBA are different languages with different goals.  VBA was built to allow it to integrate seamlessly with the MSSQLServer.  JavaScript in its native form has no relational-database functionality at all.  It's meant more for manipulating web pages through the DOM.  (It can do more than that, but that's its primary function.) While VBA can do some of the things Javascript can do, it's a rather clunky way (IMHO) of doing so and narrowly focused on a rather specific set of problems that are tied to very specific software and hardware infrastructures.  While that functionality might be nice to have in some cases, most of the JavaScript you see on the web today isn't interested in databases at all.

It's not clear to me what source of data you're trying to connect to but if you are specifically looking for a JavaScript data solution you might want to look into something like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), and the code libraries that have been developed specifically for that. And there are tons of other JS [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/database-js) that are relational-data or database-specific, and you can search places like [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) for those.  Or you can combine JavaScript with languages that inherently include database functionality, and [PHP](http://www.php.net/) is an excellent example of that.

Comment: Thanks for the background. As you can probably tell, I have 0 experience at all in Javascript, I am just trying to figure out a way of accomplishing what I used to be able to do in Excel via VBA, in Sheets via their scripting alternative. The "shortcomings" that were frustrating me make more sense now based on your explanation, thanks again.